# Loading Image during the UIPageViewController Transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have `UIPageViewController` class, where I collect all image URLs (`nTempElements`) and pass it to `ContentViewController` where image loading happens. When user scrolls back or forward, it always shows the first viewcontroller image as a placeholder until the scrolled page image is getting loaded.

If I remove `dispatch_async` in the `ContentViewController`, then this issue is no longer valid, but it is little bit less responsive to touch event, because image loading happens on the Main Thread.

Any recommendation or solution for this issue?

**PageContentViewController.m**

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{    
    if (([self.nTempElements count] == 0) || (index >= [self.nTempElements count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageURL = self.nTempElements[index];
    return pageContentViewController;
}
```

**ContentViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.newsImageView setImage:image];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: After you initialize the `pageContentViewController`, i don't see you call `setImage` anywhere, except after image loaded. How can `pageContentViewController` shows the first viewcontroller image? Did you set image for `newsImageView` anywhere else?

Comment: Why don't you cache image if already downloaded ? Look for some third party library like AlamofireImage or SDWebImage can help you here

Answer (score 0):

Might be help follow this code!!

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:self.imageURL completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (data) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if (image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    self.newsImageView.image = image;
            });
        }
    }
}];
[task resume];
```